# How to find AWS billing per resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-billing

I want to perform detail analysis on billing. For that I want to find usage report per resource. For example, In amazon Kinesis I want to find usage report of each stream for each day. From AWS usage report I am able to get only for the whole Kinesis service. Is it possible to get usage report of individual Stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the granularity of your billing reports by [using Cost Allocation Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html). The Cost Explorer allows you to filter by tags and - with a good tagging strategy - helps you better understand the cost of individual resources.

Comment: I was not aware of tags. I added a new tag to my existing resource. But I am unable to view it on cost explorer. Is it possible to view tag on newly created tag for older resource?

Comment: Cost Explorer updates your data at least every 24 hours. Alternatively, you can configure your AWS Cost and Usage Report to be generated on an hourly schedule.

Comment: Make sure that you enabled "Cost allocation tags" in the billing service (AWS Cost Management) - once you enabled the relevant tags, you'll be able to see them in Cost Explorer and the CUR (Cost and allocation report)